# Basing a query on merging two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
Visitor(id, sessions, last_seen, first_seen, ...)
CustomData(id, visitor_id, field, value, type)
```

The visitor table maintains data that my application track for people who visit my application.

The `custom_data` table holds user supplied data that users can send to my application to track additional information on visitors (they specify the name of the datafield and its value and type). Each row is a seperate piece of data. ie. field: value, and a visitor can have many entries in the `custom_data` table

I'd like to be able to query this data in homogeneous way, meaning: I'd like to be able to ask

Give me all visitors with 5 or more sessions (note session on `visitors` table) or give me visitors with 5 or more `purchases_made`(field column on `custom_data`, fieldname and value supplied by user)

Is there a clever way to accomplish this so I can avoid having lots of conditional like (is this field is specified on visitors table, do this, if it is on custom_data, do this other thing instead).

I hope it makes sense, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected outcome given that sample data along with your own attempt(s) and how/why they didn't work. Also, this would be good to read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do something like:

select id 
from .visitors 
group by id
having (id) > 4

and the same thing with purchases made.  The simplest but not necessarily most efficient would be then to either join the data or use windowed functions... but like Tom H.'s comment a little more detail is needed to exactly answer you question.